# Server returning 500 error only when calling preventDefault on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a simple AJAX post on an ASP.NET MVC form without redirecting and the server keeps returning a 500 error. When I remove preventDefault everything works but the page changes and I see 5000 outputted to it.

**AJAX Request:**

```
$( ".commentForm" ).submit(function(e) {

    // Without this it works fine, but it is needed so we don't leave page
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Products/CreateComment",
            data: $(id).serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**ASP.NET MVC6 Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult CreateComment(ProductCommentViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ProductComment prodComment = new ProductComment()
        {
            FeedPostId = vm.ProductComment.FeedPostId,
            Content = vm.ProductComment.Content
        };

        return Json(5000);
    }
    return HttpBadRequest();
}
```

Comment: Without `e.preventDefault();`, form will be submitted..Server side script is causing issue..

Comment: @RayonDabre so what are you saying I should do? As a test I am simply just trying to return 5000 as the data.

Comment: Check whether valid data is being sent over server..If yes then review your controller code...`asp.net` is not my cup of tea..

Comment: instead of `dataType: "html"` it should be `dataType: "JSON"`

Comment: Just changed it to json and still no go, I am pretty sure when using .serialize dataType: html is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You ajax method is throwing an exception on the server because you method expects data which is `ProductCommentViewModel` but using `data: $(id).serialize(),` is not senfing your model. You need to change the ajax to use

```
data: $this.serialize(),
dataType: "json",
```

i.e. the data you send is the serialized form values and because yout method is returning json, the `dataType` must also be `'json'`

Comment: Thanks! using $this.serialize() worked perfectly, however not sure why using the ID didn't work, seems like it should have. It still returns the 5000 without dataType set to json, but I will make it json since I am returning json.

Comment: Because `ID` is not `ProductCommentViewModel` and your method just initializes a new instance of `ProductCommentViewModel` so `FeedPostId = vm.ProductComment.FeedPostId,` throws a `NullReferenceException` because `ProductComment` is `null` (you really need to learn to debug your code)

Comment: The thing that threw me off was when e.preventDefault wasn't there my view model was bound properly... and everything worked even when using the ID.. Can you explain that? I was debugging.

Comment: No it was not working correctly. What was happening was that without `e.preventDefault()` you were doing both the ajax call and the normal submit. The ajax call was throwing an exception but you never saw it because at the same time the normal submit was occurring (which resulted in a redirect)

Comment: The last thing I need you to explain is why $(this) is not the same as $(#formID)? They both should get me the form shouldn't they?

Comment: I assume you mean `$( ".commentForm" )`? It depends where you declare it. Your use of `var $this = $(this);` is setting the form to a variable named `$this` which you use inside the ajax function. But if you were to use `data: $(this).serialize(),` then `$(this)` is not the form - its the ajax function so it would not be serializing the form.

Comment: No, when I was doing var id = $this.attr("id"); I was getting the ID of the form. Each form has its own ID i.e. add-comment-200. The way you have me doing it is way better because I can simply use 'this' which is the form and allows me to get rid of the ID, but I still want to understand how I am not getting the same form object using the form's id. <form id="add-comment-@product.Id" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="CreateComment" class="formComment".... In this case would $("#add-comment-200") be the same as 'this'?

Comment: Yes it would, but your use of `var id = $this.attr("id");` returns `'add-comment-200'` (not `'#add-comment-200'`) and so it would then need to be `$('#' + id).serialize();`